# Python rdflib Not Parsing Creative Commons License Information Correctly

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib

I was using rdflib version 3.2.3 and everything was working fine.  After upgrading to 4.0.1 I started getting the error:

> RDFa parsing Error! 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5454: ordinal not in range(128)

I tried various way to make this work but so far have not succeeded.  Below are my attempts.

In each case I:

```py
from rdflib import Graph
```

First attempt:

```py
>>> lg =Graph()
>>> len(lg.parse('http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/alex/Projects/RDF/rdfEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1002, in parse
parser.parse(source, self, **args)
File "/home/alex/Projects/RDF/rdfEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/structureddata.py", line 268, in parse
vocab_cache=vocab_cache)
File "/home/alex/Projects/RDF/rdfEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/structureddata.py", line 148, in _process
_check_error(processor_graph)
File "/home/alex/Projects/RDF/rdfEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/structureddata.py", line 57, in _check_error
raise Exception("RDFa parsing Error! %s" % msg)
Exception: RDFa parsing Error! 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4801: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Second attempt:

```py
>>> lg =Graph()
>>> len(lg.parse('http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/rdf'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/alex/Projects/RDF/rdfEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1002, in parse
parser.parse(source, self, **args)
File "/home/alex/Projects/RDF/rdfEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/rdfxml.py", line 570, in parse
self._parser.parse(source)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
self.feed(buffer)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
File "/home/alex/Projects/RDF/rdfEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/rdfxml.py", line 160, in endElementNS
self.current.end(name, qname)
File "/home/alex/Projects/RDF/rdfEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/rdfxml.py", line 461, in property_element_end
current.data, literalLang, current.datatype)
File "/home/alex/Projects/RDF/rdfEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/term.py", line 541, in __new__
raise Exception("'%s' is not a valid language tag!"%lang)
Exception: 'i18n' is not a valid language tag!
```

Third attempt: gives no errors but also does not give any results

```py
>>> lg =Graph()
>>> len(lg.parse('http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/rdf', format='rdfa'))
0
```

So someone please tell me what I am dong wrong!  :)

Comment: The example does not work any more rdflib.plugin.PluginException: No plugin registered for (text/html, <class 'rdflib.parser.Parser'>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Graham replied on the rdflib mailinglist, there is a html5lib problem - we will pin it correctly for python 2 for the next release, but for now just do:

```
pip install html5lib==0.95
```

The second problem is a problem in the data from creative commons, "i18n" really isn't a valid language tag according to rfc5646. I added the check, but in retrospect it seems to strict to raise an exception. I guess I'll change it to a warning.